# Error on pandas.read_hdf

Tags: python-2.7, pandas

I created an HDF5 file with:

```
pfad = "E:\Geld\Handelssysteme\Kursdaten\Ivolatity/Daten Monatsoptionen/ODAX_alles.h5"
df.to_hdf(pfad,'df', format='table')
```

Now I want to read and put a portion of the table back into a dataframe without reading all of the lines in the file.

I tried

```
df=pandas.read_hdf('pfad', 'df', where = ['expiration<expirations[1] and expiration>=expirations[0]'])
```

where expirations is a list that contains datetime64[ns] values and I want to get a dataframe where the values in column "expiration" are between `expirations[1]` and `expirations[0]`.

However, I get a `KeyError: 'No object named df in the file'`

What would the right syntax be?

Answer (score 1):

The following works instead:

```
hdf=pandas.HDFStore(pfad)
df=hdf.select('df')
```